# Dryer vents and mice

Tags: dryer, vent, mice

We have been dealing with mice since the fall, eventually we got a pest control company and their recommendation after setting their baits for ~3weeks is to seal all the cracks and holes.

One thing they mentioned though was to grate the bathroom and dyer ventilation. We use since our dryer vents through the attic we installed [this vent](https://www.amazon.ca/LAMBRO-LAO143W-4-Inch-Plastic-Under-Eave/dp/B000H5PTSG/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_60_lp_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=YXY67VS9WKATABS8KHZR), which opens and closes when the dryer is running, however the pest control company insists it's one of the ways they are coming in and we need to grate it. I'm a little concerned about that since dryer lint can get stuck in there and cause a blockage, and frankly i'm not even sure how mice can get into that type of vent. What do you guys think?

Comment: I would think mice would have a tough time making it in since it is in the eave pointing down. I have seen mice damage on dryer ducts that were close to the ground the bugger got in through the flap and chewed through the flex duct at the back of the dryer.

Comment: Mice are good climbers, and a vent blowing warm air would be attractive in the colder seasons, so it's feasible that they are entering at that point (look for droppings - mice seem to poop almost continuously, so their travel paths are pretty obvious). Something like [this](http://www.bestmaterials.com/detail.aspx?ID=19979&gclid=CjwKCAiAm7LSBRBBEiwAvL1-L3u7NCoS4beeebOKhn6Xtlk3rjM-sfCMGY5uUKx1w8mkX5uEEwT1nxoCGWgQAvD_BwE) could work - there's a big enough gap between it and the vent that it would take a very long time for lint to block it. Just be sure to inspect at regular intervals.

Comment: That said... you might want to check local building codes to see if this is even allowed. The [international residential code](https://dryerbox.com/sites/default/files/conversions/pdfs/code/2012_IRC_Dryer_Exhaust_Duct.pdf) for example says "screens shall not be installed at duct termination". Whether the product I linked counts as a "screen" could be up for debate. And which codes your locality has adopted might make a difference.